# In CloudFormation, how do I target a Lambda alias in Events::Rule

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm trying to trigger a Lambda:alias (the alias is key here) on a schedule. The following code errors out with

> "SampleLambdaLiveAlias is not valid. Reason: Provided Arn is not in
> correct format. (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400;
> Error Code: ValidationException;"

How do I properly target the lambda:alias in CloudFormation? I've tried `!Ref`, `!Sub` and just the logical name.

My custom-resource approach to retrieving the latest lambda version appears to be a necessary evil of setting up the "live" alias because AWS maintains old lambda versions, even after you delete the lambda and stack AND a valid version is required for a new alias. If anyone knows a more elegant approach to that problem, please see: [how-to-use-sam-deploy-to-get-a-lambda-with-autopublishalias-and-additional-alises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63821300/how-to-use-sam-deploy-to-get-a-lambda-with-autopublishalias-and-additional-alis)

```
SampleLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
        FunctionName: SampleLambda
        AutoPublishAlias: staging
        CodeUri: src/
        Handler: SampleLambda.handler
        MemorySize: 512
        Runtime: nodejs12.x
        Role: !GetAtt SampleLambdaRole.Arn
SampleLambdaLiveAlias:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    Properties:
        FunctionName: !Ref SampleLambdaFunction
        FunctionVersion: !GetAtt SampleLambdaGetMaxVersionFunction.version
        Name: live
SampleLambdaFunctionScheduledEvent:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
        State: ENABLED
        ScheduleExpression: rate(1 minute) # same as cron(0/1 * * * ? *)
        Description: Run SampleLambdaFunction once every 5 minutes.
        Targets:
        - Id: EventSampleLambda
            Arn: SampleLambdaLiveAlias
```

Comment: `!Ref` should be enough. Can you provide detailed error message? You have also indentation issues in your `Targets`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is in the last line of the piece of configuration you shared. In order to get the resource ARN you need to use Ref intrinsic function such as, `!Ref SampleLambdaLiveAlias`:

```
SampleLambdaFunctionScheduledEvent:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
        State: ENABLED
        ScheduleExpression: rate(1 minute) # same as cron(0/1 * * * ? *)
        Description: Run SampleLambdaFunction once every 5 minutes.
        Targets:
        - Id: EventSampleLambda
            Arn: !Ref SampleLambdaLiveAlias
```

Be aware that Ref intrinsic function may return different things for different types of resources. For Lambda alias it returns the ARN, just what you need.

You can check the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-alias.html) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks to your answer and Undo in my editor, I can now see my dyslexia was getting the better of me and I was trying to use `$Ref` insead of `!Ref` :P  Cheers!

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it helped you resolve the issue.